# How to fix 'Specifier python_version does not match 2.7 (3.6).'

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

I'm trying to install django with pipenv on ubuntu 18.04 but the problem is that pipenv always install python 2.7 inside the project. When I type pipenv --python 3.6 it give me this error message: "pipenv check will surely fail.".
And when I type pipenv check I get this message: "Checking PEP 508 requirements…
Specifier python_version does not match 2.7 (3.6).
Failed!". Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, it's pretty silly that you can't actually select the python version you want to run in a virtual environment. My solution:

`pip uninstall pipenv`

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1050

Take a look at that. The only "solution" right now is to remove the python_version key from the Pipfile.

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1050#issuecomment-346203646 The attitude of the main maintainer of pipenv seems to indicate it is just better not to use pipenv...